# Zoom in with mouse wheel doesn't work on my website

Tags: wordpress, browser, zooming, mousewheel, divi

We are trying to take over our website from the company who created it.

So, we are searching through all tiny mistakes and trying to solve.

We are using Wordpress and Divi for the website.

The problem is;

Our website does not zoom in our zoom out via mouse wheel but it does with CTRL+ or CTRL-.

Any helps will be bless for us, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

- Open the static-map.php file
- Seek for the word *scrollWheel* (it should be ´the declaration of a variable)
- Set its value to **true**

Comment: We couldn't find static-map.php file.